# Not able to iterate arraylist which contains linked hashmap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I am trying to iterate over an instance of `ArrayList` of Object class using a for loop:

```
for(PayloadDTO payloadDTO:payloadDTOList) {
    if(payloadDTO.getEntType().equals(CommonConstants.CUSTOMENTTYPEROLEID.RES_ROLE_TYPE)) {
        resRoleNameList.add(payloadDTO.getEntName());
    } 
}
```

[image]

That gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.alnt.fabric.external.model.PayloadDTO
    at com.alnt.fabric.external.rbac.service.ExternalFabricService.loadImpactedUserCount(ExternalFabricService.java:384)
    at com.alnt.fabric.external.rbac.controller.ExternalFabricController.loadImpactedUserCount(ExternalFabricController.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

So I tried to convert it using the code below:

```
payloadDTOList = convert(payloadDTOList.toString(), List<PayloadDTO.class>);


    public static <T> T convert(String json, Class<T> type) throws ALNTApplicationException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ALNTApplicationException(FabricComponentErrorCodes.ACTION_HANDLER_ERROR_CODE,"Object conversion error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your iteration loop here? I think problem is the way you are trying to iterate it.

Comment: @Jainik added loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a for loop with casting

```
for (int i=0; i < payloadDTOList.size(); i++) {
    PayloadDTO payloadDTO = (PayloadDTO) payloadDTOList.get(i);       
    if(payloadDTO.getEntType().equals(CommonConstants.CUSTOMENTTYPEROLEID.RES_ROLE_TYPE)) {
      resRoleNameList.add(payloadDTO.getEntName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the ArrayList and create a new list of objects based on that.Then you can iterate payloadDTOList2 using forEach.

```
List<PayloadDTO> payloadDTOList2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < payloadDTOList.size(); i++) {
   LinkedHashMap<String,String> linkedHash = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) payloadDTOList.get(i);
   PayloadDTO payloadDTO =  new PayloadDTO();
   payloadDTO.setEntType(linkedHash.get("EntType"));
   payloadDTO.setEntName(linkedHash.get("EntName"));
   payloadDTOList2.add(payloadDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for convert json array to collection use this :

```
payloadDTOList = 
    convert(
        payloadDTOList.toString(),
        TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType( 
            List.class , 
            PayloadDTO.class
        )
    );
```

and change method to:

```
public static <T> T convert(String json, JavaType type) throws ALNTApplicationException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ALNTApplicationException(FabricComponentErrorCodes.ACTION_HANDLER_ERROR_CODE,"Object conversion error");
    }
}


public static <T> T convert(String json, Class<T> type) throws ALNTApplicationException {
    return convert( 
            json , 
            TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType( 
                    type 
            ) 
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. now its giving me an error on read value :- The method readValue(String, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, JavaType)

Comment: Still getting same issue

Comment: what issue still?

Comment: an error on read value :- The method readValue(String, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, JavaType)

Comment: did you add two types of overloading method?
this method has a `String , Class<T>` argument?

Comment: for JavaType , did you `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType`

Comment: it's worked for me.
please try this:
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;`
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;`

Answer (score -2):

As we can see in snap, the list `payloadDTOList` is of type `LinkedHashMap` and you are trying to assign it in `PayloadDTO` at `for(PayloadDTO payloadDTO:payloadDTOList)`.

If you are sure that all the objects in list `payloadDTOList` is of type `LinkedHashMap` than use like: `for(LinkedHashMap map:payloadDTOList)`

If you are not sure of type of objects in list than use normal for loop like.

```
for (int i=0; i < payloadDTOList.size(); i++) {
    if(payloadDTOList.get(i) instanceof PayloadDTO)
         PayloadDTO payloadDTO = (PayloadDTO) payloadDTOList.get(i);
    }
}
```